# Querying Azure table storage using .NET reflection

Tags: c#, linq, azure, reflection, azure-table-storage

I want to write a function `GetAny()` that can query and return a row from *any* table in the Azure Table Storage just by supplying the table name `tableName` and the entity type `T` with LINQ. So far what I've tried is as follows:

```
public T GetAny<T>(TableServiceContext tableStorageServiceContext, 
    string tableName, string partitionKey, string applicationName)
{
    var results = from c in tableStorageServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>(tableName)
        where ((T)c).PartitionKey == partitionKey
        select c;

    var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery();
    return query.Execute().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

, which does not compile since I'm not allowed to cast `c` into `T` like I'm trying to.

I also tried to default to `TableServiceEntity` , but then I still have to cast the resulting `TableServiceEntity` into the *true* entity type after `GetAny()` has been invoked:

```
TableServiceEntity GetAny(string tableName, string partitionKey)
{
    var results = from c in _tableStorageServiceContext.CreateQuery<TableServiceEntity>(tableName)
                  where c.PartitionKey == partitionKey 
                  select c;

    var query = results.AsTableServiceQuery();
    return query.Execute().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Is there a way of doing this with .NET reflection, or perhaps there are other ways of querying the Azure Table Storage that supports not having to implicitly specify the entity type?

Comment: Have you looked at DynamicTableEntity (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dynamictableentity.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to query from any Storage Table:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns table entities
/// </summary>
public List<dynamic> GetEntities(string tableName, int takeCount, string filters)
    {

        var table = TableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

        var tableQuery = !filters.IsEmpty()
                             ? new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Where(filters).Take(takeCount)
                             : new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Take(takeCount);

        var tableResult = table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery);

        List<dynamic> dynamicCollection = tableResult.ToDynamicList();

        return dynamicCollection;
    }
```

The extension method `ToDynamicList` basically reads through each entity on the result and maps the property value as `dynamic` type. Storage Library by default hides the values behind bunch of properties such as `.BinaryValue`, 'BoolValue'

I wrote a generic Storage Table Browser which you can find on [github](https://github.com/amithegde/AzureTableBrowser)